# Find and replace Android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, refactoring, rename

Is there a way to find and replace all occurrences of a word in an entire project (not just a single class using refactor -> rename) and also maintain case, either in Android Studio or using a command line script?

For example, Supplier has to go to Merchant, supplier -> merchant, SUPPLIER -> MERCHANT. My boss wants me to change all instances of supplier with merchant for a project I'm working on. I've been doing it for about an hour and I know I'm wasting my time. Let me know of any time-saving suggestions.

Comment: One way to do it is right click in the solution on the folder structure and there choose replace in path.

Answer (score 724, accepted):

I think the shortcut that you're looking for is:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> on Windows and Linux/Ubuntu

<kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> on macOS (IntelliJ IDEA Classic keymap)

<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> on macOS (macOS keymap)

ref: [source](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/find-and-replace-in-path.html)

Comment: I'm on OS X and it was still Ctrl+Shift+R

Comment: This worked wonderfully! I had to rename a class in it's entirety, including comments, getters, setters, constructors, new calls, THE WORKS, but android studio's refactor was bugging out on me. Ctrl+Shift+R however, ignored all that and hard changed the files after which the project had to be reloaded. Do select "preserve case" or it will mess up everything.

Comment: at OS X at least for me was Command instead of Ctrl button. Just for the new mac - android studio users.

Comment: Doesn't work for me anymore. I think this shortcut was removed. Anyone else seeing the same? Edit>Find>Replace In Path is still there of course.

Comment: Command-Shift-R brings up Replace in Path dialogue for me  in OSX El Capitan, Android Studio 2.1.3.

Comment: also `Ctrl + Shift + R` for Ubuntu(Linux)

Comment: On Mac OS it is `CMD` + `R`

Comment: On all platforms, you can go to Preferences>Keymap, then search "Replace" to see keymaps for "replace"-related commands. This is especially helpful if you're not using the default keymap

Answer (score 123):

On *Windows*:

Find : <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>

Find And Replace In Single Class: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>

Find And Replace In Whole Project: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>

on *OS X* ,it is similar, just replace <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> with <kbd>Command</kbd>

Answer (score 68):

In Android studio, 
Edit -- > Find --> Replace in path, this will check in whole project including comments and code.

Comment: This is the correct answer in Android Studio on macOS. The only full-project search/replace sweeper.

Answer (score 19):

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> to find and replace codes in the class where you are...

Answer (score 16):

Use <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> or <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> in OSX

Comment: this is only affect to current open file

Answer (score 15):

If you use refactor->rename for the name of the file, everywhere the file is used in your project the refactor will replace it.

I have already rename variables, xml file, java file, multiple drawable and after the operation I could build directly without error.

Do a back-up of your project and try to see if it work for you.

Comment: The default shortcut for rename is Shift + F6. ;-)

Answer (score 7):

The shortcuts are

**On Windows**  : <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>

**On Mac** : <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>

Answer (score 4):

In Android studio,

1. **ctrl + r** - will do find and replace with in a file
2. **ctrl + shift + r** - will do find and replace in whole project

[image: Find and replace with in file]

Answer (score 3):

Try using: Edit -> Find -> Replace in path...

Answer (score 2):

**ctrl + H** .....
its give option to replace word from class.

Comment: But it does not give replace option.

Answer (score 2):

This is very simple.

Use `Ctrl+R` for Windows .

Use `Cmd+R` for mac.

Comment: This will search/replace on the current file, not in the entire project

Answer (score 1):

I think the previous answers missed the most important (non-trivial) aspect of the OP's question, i.e., how to perform the search/replace in a "time saving" manner, meaning **once**, *not* three times, and "maintain case" originally present.

> On the pane, check "**[X] Preserve Case**" before clicking the Replace All button

This performs a case-aware "smart" replacement in one pass:

```
apple -> orange
Apple -> Orange
APPLE -> ORANGE
```

Also, for peace of mind, don't forget to check the code into the VCS before performing sweeping project-wide replacements.