# Changing multiple buttons type in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I created an application in flutter where I put Raisedbutton's everywhere. I want to change them all in Neumorphicbutton. Is there a way to change all Raisedbutton's into NeummorphicButton without editing one by one?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use refactor tool to change all occurrence of Raisedbutton to Neumorphicbutton. If u want to change all of them at once

Comment: Thank you @MerMonkey But inside of refractor tool I have many other choices. Wichone should I chose. Also I am using AndroidStudio

Comment: I can rename (refractor) an Widget or a Class name but not a RaisedButton.

Comment: When I rename the RaisedButton it says "The class 'raisedButton' is defined outside of the project, so cannot be renamed."

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20249274/find-and-replace-android-studio I think this can help you

Comment: It is not about refactoring the raisedButton itself all you need to do is change all occurrence. You can do it even in ms word if u see fit :')

Comment: And can I ask another question?

Comment: Yeah, ask away.

Comment: In AndroidStudio (on mac) how can I see the functionality of for example of a  raisedButton? (like the text etc...)

Comment: I use vsc myself so I don't really know how to turn it on in AndroidStudio. Try to search in plugins for code snipsets or sth. In vsc I just need to press ctrl + .

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you want all the buttons to change into a neumorphic button style by clicking a single button , you can use the `Onpressed()` function and have it call `SetState` , in which you can change each and every button to Neumorphic style