# how to search and replace all occurrences of the old package name in all files in flutter

Tags: flutter

Is there a way for me to search and replace all occurrences of the old package name in all files of my flutter project using android studio?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find and replace Android studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20249274/find-and-replace-android-studio)

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this?
[replace in path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2TUBu.jpg)

right click on directory `lib`, select `Replace in path`