# Remove quotes and braces in Android Studio in editor

Tags: java, android, string

Is there a possibility to easily remove surrounding quotes, braces, etc from a certain text element in my Android Studio project?

More specifically without manually removing quotes and test and retyping?

For example:

eg 1 **`"with quotes"` should become `with quotes` with minimal effort?**

eg 2 **`{with braces}` should become `with braces` with minimal effort?**

> I can do it just only by selecting words inside quotes and deleting both words and quotes and then again retyping same words.

***Please help me if there is a way in Android Studio***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By selecting the code, and then using replaceAll should work.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20249274/find-and-replace-android-studio

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't appear to be a way to do this.

I typically make use of keyboard shortcuts to move the cursor.

Here is a complete list, from *Wikipedia*.
*[Table of keyboard shortcuts – Text editing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Table_of_keyboard_shortcuts#Text_editing)*.

So, to remove the quotes, I'd use the *start-of-line* or *end-of-line* shortcut.